# Power Bi Embedded - Delay in applying default filter

Tags: powerbi-embedded

Step by step to see this delay, since this Angular demo default filter doesn't work and javascript demo have no interface way to do that:

1. Access this demo:
   https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html
2. Click on "Embed Report"
3. Open console from your browser
4. Execute this function:  _Embed_EmbedWithDefaultFilter()

There we are the 0.5 seconds that affects directly the client data confidence
Does anyone knows something to help improving this?

Answer (score 0):

There is always a 'delay' in processing the selected filter, as the data needs to be queried again and refersh the visuals data.

However, if you'd like to load the report already with the filter applied - you can use the filters property in the load configuration when using the Power BI Embedded JS SDK